# Grep a string from json data

Tags: text-processing, json

I got json data in the following format, I prefer to use use `sed` or `awk`, `jq` is not supported, `grep -o` is not supported on solaris box

```
[{"FRUIT":"APPLE","CAR":"FORESTER","COMPANY":"SUBARU","MAKE":"2015","CITY":"UNION CITY","STATE":0,"COUNTRY":0,"LOCATION":0,"RANK":"1"},{"FRUIT":"MANGO","CAR":"OUTBACK","COMPANY":"SUBARU","MAKE":"2017","CITY":"EDISON","STATE":0,"COUNTRY":0,"LOCATION":0,"RANK":"2"},{"....."}]
```

I am looking to extract data of 2nd column

```
"FORESTER"
"OUTBACK"
```

Comment: Explain why `jq` is "not supported".

Answer (score 3):

You can use `json_xs`, it is usually installed by default on any system supporting Perl:

```
json_xs -f json -t json-pretty < file | grep '"CAR"' | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d '"' -f2
```

Or with Python:

```
python3 -m json.tool file | grep '"CAR"' | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d '"' -f2
```

Comment: python3.4 -m json.tool file | grep "CAR" | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d '"' -f2 ,     ****it worked****

Comment: Assuming "state" is any US state, may break on `CAROLINA`.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks, I believe it shouldn't catch such examples now.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below command

```
$ sed "s/{/\n/g" file.txt | awk -F, 'NF>=2{split($2,Arr,":");print Arr[2]}'
"FORESTER"
"OUTBACK"
```

we break the single line into multiple lines by using sed command, then using the awk, we are retrieving the second column value

Comment: Note that the user is using Solaris, where the default `sed` can't replace a character with a newline using the `s` command.

Comment: Also note that this would break if the data contained `:` or `{` in the values.

Comment: @Kusalananda, `sed` on any system can replace anything with newline as long as the newline in the replacement is expressed as backslash followed by a newline character (not `\n` in any case which is a GNU extension)

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant approach, but this works on your example data:

```
$ tr , '\n' < file | awk -F: '{if(/\{/){NR=1}}NR==2{print $2}'
"FORESTER"
"OUTBACK"
```

The `tr` will replace all `,` with newlines. The awk will reset the default `NR` variable to `0` when it sees a `{`. Since `NR` holds the current line number and incremented automatically on each line, this means that it will be `2` only on the second line of each set of key-value pairs. So then, when `NR` is `2`, we print the second `:`-separated field.

---

Alternatively, use a proper scripting language that supports JSON data. For example, in `perl`:

```
$ perl -M"JSON" -lne 'my $json = decode_json($_); 
                      foreach $f (@{$json}){print $f->{"CAR"};}' file
FORESTER
OUTBACK
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to terdon's answer:

```
sed s'/[,{}]/\n/g' < file.json | grep '^\"CAR\"\:' | cut -d ':' -f2
```

After Kusalananda's note about Solaris not supporting the above `sed` style, it can be replaced by the following `tr` option:

```
tr ',{}' '\n' < file.json | grep '^\"CAR\"\:' | cut -d ':' -f2
```

Rudimentary splits the json into each field to its separate line by replacing all `,` `{` and `}` characters with a new line. Then grepping through the results for lines starting with `"CAR":` and printing the value after the `:`.

Should be reasonably capable of parsing all similar json setups without doing too complex stuff.

Comment: The user is on Solaris, where the default `sed` does not know how to insert newlines with  the `s` command.

Answer (score -1):

The `jq` tool, which I'm using in this answer, may be downloaded from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ (even for Solaris) and installed in a non-root user's home directory without any root access whatsoever.  It furthermore does not have any runtime dependencies at all.

---

There is no "2nd column" in a JSON document.  Your document may as well be written

```
[
  {
    "FRUIT": "APPLE",
    "CAR": "FORESTER",
    "COMPANY": "SUBARU",
    "MAKE": "2015",
    "CITY": "UNION CITY",
    "STATE": 0,
    "COUNTRY": 0,
    "LOCATION": 0,
    "RANK": "1"
  },
  {
    "FRUIT": "MANGO",
    "CAR": "OUTBACK",
    "COMPANY": "SUBARU",
    "MAKE": "2017",
    "CITY": "EDISON",
    "STATE": 0,
    "COUNTRY": 0,
    "LOCATION": 0,
    "RANK": "2"
  }
]
```

The added whitespace does not affect the actual JSON data.

To extract the values of all entries corresponding to the key `CAR`, use `jq`, a command line JSON parser:

```
$ jq '.[].CAR' file.json
"FORESTER"
"OUTBACK"
```

The expression `.[].CAR` means "For each element of the top-most array, return the value of the key `CAR`".

Would you want to have no quotes in the output, add `-r` (or `--raw-output`) to the `jq` invocation. This would return decoded data.